# setGravity both BOTTOM and CENTER programmatically

Tags: android, button, gravity

I'm having problems placing a button inside a space of a GridLayout.

```
final Button prevButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); // <-----------------------
prevButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
prevButton.setBackgroundDrawable(menuButton);
prevButton.setLayoutParams(param);
prevButton.setWidth(menuButtonWidth);
prevButton.setText("<");
```

I want the button to be at the very bottom of the screen, but I also want it to be in the center of it's space (like param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)). Is there a way to combine Gravity.BOTTOM and Gravity.CENTER programmatically (No XML)? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this .

```
param.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: It's | not || (or) . It has a Special meaning in java . Please google for more . Or take a look here . 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER + Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: In Android API Gravity class CENTER Constant value is 17 and Bottom value is 80 if you want both of them make summation of it 80+17=97 which specifies Center with Bottom.